# Connecting Stacked Columns in MSChart

Tags: asp.net, .net, mschart

Is it possible to connect the Columns in a 100% Stacked MSChart chart with lines for each colored block (series)?

I'd like to know if there's some custom attribute or option I've missed, before adding new series manually, and trying to "align" them with the stacked bars...

Comment: what do you mean by connect the columns? Can you upload a pic of what you want to do ?

Comment: I mean, show a line that connects the top borders of stacked bars with the same colors, like this:

https://encrypted-tbn2.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ4AuoKT6sRVq88mthQIbM2QSx31ShqppifYq0WuD88bCAzzKC_cA

Comment: You could probably achieve this using a 100% `StackedArea` ... by doubling each value to create the fake columns. It would require some manual work to get the labels to behave.